# cat in process substitution hangs: what is it waiting for?

Tags: bash, shell-script, prompt, process-substitution

I have this piece of code using **Process Substitution.**

When I run it, it works fine, but it does not exit - **just hangs there waiting** for input.

Why and how to overcome?

```
prepro() { 
        in=$(< <(cat) )         # capture input
        echo -e "$in"
}

echo -e "some words" > >(prepro)
echo "FINISHED"
```

Instead if I do this, it exits immediately.

```
echo -e "$in" >>"test.log"
```

What am I missing here?

**CLARIFICATION:**
BASH 4.4.19(1)-release

On my pc, I see a difference between running `echo -e "$in"` and running `echo -e "$in" >>"test.log"`.

The former does not give me a prompt (but I can run commands normally).
I get:

```
user@server:~$ ./test.sh
FINISHED
user@server:~$ some words
█
```

I have to press ENTER to get my prompt back.

The latter gives me the prompt normally.

```
user@server:~$ ./test.sh
FINISHED
user@server:~$ █
```

I am curious if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: So it doesn't hang. Look closely: your prompt is before `some words`. I'm sure this has been asked before, hang on.

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate of an earlier question that explains why this happens. If you can't figure out how to solve your _actual problem_, post your actual code, because in this toy example, the obvious fix is not to use process substitution.